# Annotation "service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-cross-zone-load-balancing-enabled" = "true" not working with network load balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-eks

I am using below annotation in my terraform script to create kubernetes service with internal network load balancer and enable cross zone load balancing.
However, cross zone load balancing is not enabled after execution of the script.

```
annotations = {
      "service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-type" = "nlb"
      "service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-internal" = "true"  
      "service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-cross-zone-load-balancing-enabled" = "true"
    }
```

If I remove the load-balancer-type from the annotations block, it creates classic load balancer with cross zone load balancing enabled.

Is this annotation not supported for network load balancer?

Comment: [AWS LB controller tests](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-load-balancer-controller/blob/8409bd52953c21d0d3f0603a05300e9ee6e134a6/test/e2e/service/nlb_instance_target_test.go#L86-L97) suggest that this shoud work. Did you check the logs for errors?

Comment: Code executes without any error but I couldn't able to see the changes.